# Extract all the certificates from a file in python

Tags: python, regex, file, parsing, certificate

I am new to python. I have a file with trusted CA certificates. File can have any number of certificates in this format:

> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- sfsdfsfdsafs
>   -----END CERTIFICATE-----
>
> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MCUwIwYIKwYBBQUHA
>   -----END CERTIFICATE----- 
>   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- OmyeEZm0CK6ZZZpAp
>   -----END CERTIFICATE-----

I want to read all the certificated and store it in my db.
what is the most efficient way to read this file and get all the certificates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find sub-strings within a given string, then use the "re" module.

```
import re

start        = '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----'
end          = '-----END CERTIFICATE-----'
contents     = open(FILENAME).read()
certificates = re.findall(f'{start}(.*?){end}',contents,re.DOTALL)
```

The DOTALL means to search across newline characters, instead of treating individual lines separately.

I should note that you shouldn't be manually manipulating certificate files like this. If you want them in a different format or something, you should really be using openssl.

Comment: I am getting error that python version 2.7 does not support 'F' prefix

Comment: Why are people still using python 2.7, it has stopped being supported. Anyway, change the f string to start+'(.*?)'+end instead.

Comment: This worked, but I want to include start and end also in the result. What can I do for that?

Comment: Change the capture range of the re expression. '(' + start + '.*?' + end + ')'

Comment: Will it be compatible with python 3?

Comment: Yes, python3 can also concatenate strings.